# VS2008 Setup Project for C# Project

Tags: visual-studio-2008, setup-project

I've built app using wmp.dll which is Windows System File in my XP machine.
If I tried add outputs of above project to my Setup Project, VS warned that *'wmp.dll' should be excluded because its source file 'C:\WINDOWS\system32\wmp.dll' is under Windows System File Protection*.

There're three things under 'Detected Dependencies' folder. Microsoft .NET Framework, Interop.WMPLib.dll and wmp.dll.

The app works okay in my machine, of course. But if I install this into Windows Server 2003 machine, the app does not be launched. I think this is because different version of OS use different version of wmp.dll.

Anyway, how can I fix this?

ps. I've even excluded wmp.dll from the Setup Project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you've a dependency on Windows Media Player, and that isn't installed on your server machine (or at least the relevant version). Is that installed on the client?